# Package nlme, generalized least square fit with corClass ARIMA(p,d,q)

Tags: r, package, time-series, least-squares

In R, the package `nlme` can be used to fit a generalized least square model. We can fit with an ARMA correlation like

```
fm1 <- gls(Y ~X1+X2+X3,correlation = corARMA(p=2,q=1))
```

Is it possible to fit a `gls` with an ARIMA (p,d,q) (i.e. including the difference (d) parameter) as the correlation argument? Maybe something like:

```
fm2 <- gls(Y ~X1+X2+X3,correlation = corARMA(p=2,d=1,q=1))
```

I think the ARIMA is not supported by the `corClasses` in this package.

Comment: I think you'd have to write your own `corStruct` ... and it might not be trivial -- doesn't the differencing affect the regression structure as well as the correlation structure of the residuals ... ?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "regression structure" but differencing will change the correlation structure of the residuals for sure.

Comment: Again, it's been a while since I looked at this -- but does differencing `Y` first then using ARMA(2,1) give the same result ... ?